# Add Custom Filed In Sales order for admin verification

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, custom-options

Every time we need to verify the order after order placed by the customer. Our sales represent verify same order again and again. so that is possible can I add the custom field to the sales order like **verify**. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add order status "Verified" and once it is verified by you customer representative changed that order status.

Magento 1.x:

in admin menu

> System->Order Statuses

Magento 2

> Store->Settings->Order Status

Comment: You mean, here  https://snag.gy/aClm3T.jpg

Comment: Is right my understanding, https://snag.gy/aClm3T.jpg

Comment: Nope, in admin menu Under System->Order Statuses add order status :
https://prnt.sc/hzbz1l ( like in screen shot )

Comment: Once you add order status, ( prnt.sc/hzbz1l)  this will show in drop down where you are pointing ( snag.gy/aClm3T.jpg )

Comment: without touching this, is any other way exits?

Comment: This is the easiest and appropriate way, otherwise you have to create a module for it, which capture the event (i.e on order place ) and update the order status. like @Murtuza Zabuawala mentioned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71569/discussion-between-zus-and-naveed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sales_order_place_after` event in magento

if you dont know how to use event you can refer to this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154071/magento-sales-order-place-after-observer

and use your table via magento model and do whatever operation you want to do

**Example**

```
   $model = Mage::getModel('modelAlaias/modelPath');
```

and use your `$model` here

Comment: could you pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/215022/57334